# RSA Sign using a PrivateKey from a file

Tags: haskell, encryption, rsa

Using Haskell, how can you sign using an existing private key from a file?

In Python, it is as simple as -

```
import M2Crypto
rsa = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key("path/to/key")
result = rsa.sign("foo")
```

It seems you can sign using the `Codec.Crypto.RSA` module -

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/RSA-1.0.6.2/docs/Codec-Crypto-RSA.html#g:2

But I only see how to generate new private keys from that module, not use an existing one.  It seems that the `Network.TLS.Extra` module provides reading a private key from a file -

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls-extra-0.6.1/docs/Network-TLS-Extra.html#g:6

Unfortunately, the PrivateKey type exported from each of the modules are not compatible with each other -

```
Couldn't match expected type `crypto-pubkey-types-0.4.0:Crypto.Types.PubKey.RSA.PrivateKey'
            with actual type `tls-1.1.5:Network.TLS.Crypto.PrivateKey'
```

Comment: What file format are you wanting to read the private key from?  You can use crypto-openssh-pubkey to read ssh keys then use RSA (or others) to sign or perform other operations with that key.  Something like: `readAndSign file msg = (flip sign msg . throwLeft . decodePrivate) \`fmap\` readFile file`

Comment: That solution is perfect.  Please re-post your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed something similar, so I added a bit of serialization/deserialization to the package `crypto-pubkey-openssh` a while back.  It doesn't handle encrypted or ECC keys, but suffices for most needs.

As my comment said, you want something like:

```
import Codec.Crypto.RSA (sign)
import Crypto.PubKey.OpenSsh (decodePrivate, OpenSshPrivateKey)
import Crypto.Types.PubKey.RSA (PrivateKey)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

throwLeft :: Either String OpenSshPrivateKey -> PrivateKey
throwLeft (Right (OpenSshPrivateKeyRsa k)) = k
throwLeft (Right _) = error "Wrong key type"
throwLeft (Left s)  = error $ "Error reading keys: " ++ s

readAndSign :: FilePath -> ByteString -> IO ByteString
readAndSign file msg = (flip sign msg . throwLeft . decodePrivate) `fmap` readFile file
```

Notice this code is untested, but the building blocks should be correct.  You want to read in a private key (`readFile`, `decodePrivate`).  Perform some error checking (`throwLeft`) and sign the message (`sign`).

EDIT:
I felt it was productive to identify in what way this is longer than the Python example in the question.  It appears as though the building blocks are the same but the level of abstraction exposed by the library is very different along with the error handling (explicit vs exceptions).  If we assume the library authors did a little more work by re-exporting everything from one module and defined a helper:

```
loadKey :: FilePath -> IO PrivateKey
loadKey p = (throwLeft . decodePrivate) `fmap` readFile p
```

Then the code is nearly identical:

```
k <-loadKey keyFile
let result = sign k msg
```

Comment: While this works, I have encountered a new, slightly related issue.  The signature produced in Haskell is not matching the signature from M2Crypto.  It seemed different enough that it should be asked separately - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393920/simulating-pythons-m2crypto-sign-algorithm-in-haskell

Answer (score 3):

Using `HsOpenSSL` seems to solve the problem, not as short as python version.

```
import OpenSSL.PEM
import OpenSSL.EVP.PKey
import OpenSSL.RSA
import Data.Maybe

main = do
    keyString <- readFile "/home/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa"
    key <- readPrivateKey keyString PwNone
    let maybeRsaKey = (toKeyPair key) :: Maybe RSAKeyPair
    let rsaKey = fromJust maybeRsaKey
    print  $ rsaD rsaKey

    -- Use Codec.Crypto.RSA module to sign
```